# Какие игровые JavaScript фреймворки позволяют подключать файлы ресурсов без обращения к серверу?

Tags: javascript, файлы, разработка-игр

Подбираю фреймворк для разработки игры на JS. Но возникает одна и та же проблема при разработке: браузер не позволяет коду открывать и вообще работать с файлами локальной ФС.
Скажем, пример с фреймворком Phaser.js ну или Quintus:

> Uncaught NetworkError: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load 'file:///C:/racemath/data/sprites.json'.

Как же тогда это должно работать на мобильном устройстве без интернета или если я хочу локально отлаживаться и не хочу подымать никакого сервера, предоставляющего файлы джава-скрипту?

А второй вопрос: есть ли какие-то фреймворки, позволяющие таки подключать ресурсы из файлов, или же все это упирается в ту самую проблему запрета доступа к файловой системе ОС из браузера? Тогда я вообще не понимаю, как можно сделать портируемую на мобильные устройства игру, которой в теории не нужен никакой доступ в интернет, она самодостаточна со всеми своими внутренними ресурсами и исполняемым кодом ведь.

Comment: Всё разрабатывается на localhost, потом пакуется каким-нибудь PhoneGap.

Comment: Хм. А что мешает просто сделать:  

    <script src="RelativePathInProjectStructure.js" ></SCRIPT>

А в скрипте уже происходит назначение спрайтов (sprites.json)